# Is there a way to install an application on a remote machine that does not have sudo privileges?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04

I have set my mother up with Ubuntu and no admin privileges, so she just has a user account and no sudo. She is running 14.04 (edit - maybe 12.04). I did this as she's 81 and doesn't understand about security updates / phishing phone calls etc so it was my way of protecting her as much as possible.

Now we are in lockdown, she has an issue that is preventing her webcam working and I can't go round to solve it. I have written a bash script to install teamviewer and emailed it to her, however she can't run it without sudo. I have an account on her machine, so I got her to log out as her, and log into my account that does have sudo.

Having (painfully) got her to type the relevant commands, she ran the script (which I had log it's output) and sent me the log. Everything looked to have installed fine.

When she logs back in as her, she can't run teamviewer. I assume it's because I installed it while logged in as me so it's not available to her. First question - is this a safe assumption?

Second question then is what to do next? Should I write a script that gives her sudo access, then install Teamviewer while she's logged in as her after which I can remove her sudo access afterwards, or is there some other way I can write a script that gives her access and removes it?

I don't mind getting her to type in my password over the phone as she has little to no knowledge of what it all means and wouldn't remember it anyway. Putting it all in a script sent by email is a little more uncomfortable, so any suggestions welcome please?

Thanks, and stay safe in these crazy times.

Update:-
I just called her and got her to log in as me to try and run Teamviewer. Apparently there is an error:-
dependency is not satisfiable libc6 ( = 2.17)

A quick google suggested to install it from the command line which I tried, but my mother can't read the output of install attempt. I don't think it's installing correctly possibly due to an old version of Ubuntu. I will probably try writing a script that logs the output of the install attempt.

I realise that this is all like trying to give a haircut through the post, but in the meantime I am learning about Bash Scripts :)

Comment: Voted to close as it belongs to SuperUser. Anyway I recommend you just forward X through an ssh session or just use plain terminal via ssh if you can fix the issue with the command-line: `ssh -X youruser@yourmotherhost.example.com` (If you hopefully installed ssh-server and configured her internet router to forward port to her host, and registered your ssh public key on her computer so you can disable ssh password authentication for safety). And anyway you shall not have left her version with such an old Ubuntu 14.04 that is EOL since 6 years.

Comment: No, unfortunately no ssh access via her internet router. I did have, however she has apparently changed her broadband router without my knowledge. Agree that I should have updated her ubuntu version. That is now biting me.

Comment: Just a thought: why not add her account into sudo group? Then you could add any commands/apps in `/etc/sudoers` for her account.

Comment: I did think about that, but wasn't sure if it would be possible to do so via a bash script that I would need to send via email. Also would need to remove her from the sudo group after.